# How to print elements of an array except those containing a specific digit?

Tags: arrays, c, logic

I just started learning C language and I made this program which prints elements of an array in descending order and then print the 2-digit elements of the same array in descending order. Now I want to print elements of that array except those which contain the digit 5. This is the program I made:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int array[20] = {2,5,1,3,4,10,30,50,40,20,70,90,80,60,100,150,130,110,120,140};

    printf("original array:\n");

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", array[i]);
    }

// To sort elements of array in descending order

int i,j,temp;

for(i=0;i<20;i++)
{
        for(j=i+1;j<20;j++)
        {
           if(array[i]>array[j])
           {
               temp = array[i];

               array[i] = array[j];

               array[j] = temp;
           }
        }
}

// Now to print the sorted array

printf("arranged array in descending order:\n");

for(int x = 19;x>=0;x--)
{
    printf("%i\n", array[x]);
}

// To print only 2-digit elements of the array

printf("following are only 2-digit elements of array in descending order:\n");

for(int k = 19;k>=0;k--)
{
    if(array[k]>9 && array[k]<100)
    {
        printf("%i\n", array[k]);
    }
}
}
```

What logic should I make so that only elements containing '5' are not printed?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the problem with checking whether a number contains a digit equal to 5?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I just don't know how. As I said, I just started learning C. I searched but couldn't find it.

Comment: Please Abdullah, edit the code and try to make it best readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use functions to better organize your code. First, define a `swap()` function:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = *a;
}
```

Then, write a sorting algorithm. To follow your case:

```
void bubble_sort(int *array, int size)
{
    int i, j, swap_oper;
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
        swap_oper = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < size - i - 1; ++j) {
            if (array[j] > array[j+1]) {
                swap(&array[j], &array[j+1]);
                swap_oper = 1;
            }
        }

        if (swap_oper == 0)
            break;
    }
}
```

To print all numbers except those containing 5, define a function that checks whether a number has 5s in it:

```
int contains_five(int n)
{
    while (n != 0) {
        if (n % 10 == 5)
            return 1; // true

        n /= 10;
    }
    return 0; // false
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
void print_array(int *array, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (!contains_five(array[i]))
            printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me. It's just that the print_array function prints only those elements which contain the digit 5. But I fixed it. Thanks so much for the help! If you don't mind, can you tell my about the * you used in the swap function? What is it supposed to represent? What is the difference between (variable name) and *(variable name)?

Comment: @AbdullahMushtaq Yeah I edited the code too. Now it returns `1` if there is a `5`, `0` if there isn't.

Comment: @AbdullahMushtaq `*` means a pointer. A pointer refers to an address in memory. For example, `int *a` is pointer to an integer, while `int a` is an actual integer. Now, the reason for why `swap()` accepts two pointers rather than two values is that in C, arguments to a function are passed by value, not by reference. Meaning that they are copied: what you have inside the function is a copy of the argument, not the actual argument. When you pass a pointer (an address), that address value is copied inside the function, and you can access the actual argument by dereferencing it using `*a`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate all of your help :)

Answer (score 2):

This function returns `1` if number contains digit `d` or `0` if not.

```
int has(int x, int d)
{
    while(x)
    {
        if(abs(x % 10) == d)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        x /= 10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Those are integers stored in binary, so testing for a digit ( base 10 ) is really a matter of how it's displayed.

Try

```
char str [33];
for(int k = 19;k>=0;k--)
{
    //convert to a string first
    sprintf(str, "%d", array[k])
    //test for presence of ASCII '5'
    if(!strstr(str, '5'))
    {
        printf("%i\n", array[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `buffer.find`? There is no such thing in C.

Comment: Sorry - that was C++. adjusted so should work in C now

Comment: I would suggest testing the answers before posting here. you can compile and execute online for example: https://godbolt.org

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.